# Number of rotation invariant 6-colorings of a cube

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Consider a cube colored with six distinct colors on its six faces. How many non-equivalent colorings upto rotations are there? That is, how many ways can we color the cube so that we dont get the same colorings by rotating any colorings about any of its canaonical axes?

I think the permutation groups have a role to play here. Typivcally, is it related to automorphisms of $S_6$ under rotations, or do dihedral groups come into sight? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If the colors are distinct on all faces, how can we get the same coloring by rotation?

Comment: @Aravind so you mean to say that the required number is equal to the number of ways to color the cube using six distinct colors? Is it $6!$?But, I have seen the answer is somewhere to be a two digit number

Comment: @Aravind but, suppose if the top and bottom faces, or right and left faces are colored red and green. Then by rotating $180$ degrees on either top to bottom or right to left, dont we get the same colorings?

Comment: I think you are using the words in a very confusing/confused way. Isn't a "rotationally invariant coloring" one which is unchanged by any rotation? (And since the rotations carry any face to any other face, the only possibility is that the faces are all colored the same.)

Comment: You might want to say something along the lines of _"non-equivalent up to rotations"_.

Comment: As far as I know the phrase "automorphisms of $S_6$ under rotations" is meaningless.

Comment: I suspect that suitably recast your problem is a standard coloring one, to be solved using Burnside's Formula. The rotation group of the cube has order 24, and is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, I actually meant that

Comment: @ancientmathematician ok, so you mean the coloring of non-equivalent upto rotations could be solved using burnside formula

Comment: @IvanNeretin edited the question

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it, and would deal with $k$-colorings as well. In this case you can get the answer 30 very quickly.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks, found the exact link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma#Example_application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the six colors be $C_1,\dots, C_6$. Place the cube with the bottom colored $C_1$. There are five different choices for the top face. For each of these the other four colors can be placed on the cycle of 4 vertical faces in $4!/4=6$ ways. Hence in total, 30 colorings.

Comment: fantastic! so no burnside lemma. By the way, how would do it by burnside lemma? The wikipedia link gives way beyond three digit answer!

Comment: The groups has order 24. There are $6!$ colorings in total; the identity fixes each of these; the other 23 rotations don't fix any of them. So the number up to rotation is $\frac{1}{24}(6!+0+\dots+0)=30$.

Answer (score 2):

Paint one surface white. Choose one of $5$ remaining colors for the opposite face. The four remaining colors can be split in $3$ ways into pairs and then put in $2$ ways. This gives a total of $5\cdot3\cdot2=30$ possibilities.